# casting an enumeration to get the value associated with it?

Tags: c#, enumeration

I have an enum like:

```
public enum BlahType
{
    blahA = 1,
    blahB = 2,
    blahC = 3
}
```

if I have a string with the value 'blahB', is it possible to cast it against the enum BlahType to get the value 2?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
BlahType yourEnumValue = (BlahType) Enum.Parse(typeof(BlahType), "blahB");
```

and then

```
int yourIntValue = (int) yourEnumValue;
```

Comment: Be aware that Enum.Parse can be expensive. If you're on Compact Framework it's very expensive on each call, and if you're on full .NET then it can be expensive from a memory point of view (as stuff gets cached). So, this is the best answer but be careful about Enum.Parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) method and then cast to int.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum test
{
   VAL1,
   VAL2
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   test newTest = (test)Enum.Parse(typeof(test), "VAL2");
   Console.WriteLine(newTest.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void EnumInstanceFromString()
{

 DayOfWeek wednesday = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "Wednesday");
 DayOfWeek sunday = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "sunday", true);
 DayOfWeek tgif = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "FRIDAY", true);

 lblOutput.Text = wednesday.ToString() +
                  ".  Int value = " + 
                  (int)wednesday).ToString() + "<br>";

 lblOutput.Text += sunday.ToString() + 
                   ".  Int value = " + 
                   ((int)sunday).ToString() + "<br>";

 lblOutput.Text += tgif.ToString() + 
                   ".  Int value = " + 
                   ((int)tgif).ToString() + "<br>";

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
BlahType blah = Enum.Parse(typeof(BlahType), "blahB");
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above by a few others you would want to use:

```
        BlahType myEnum = (BlahType)Enum.Parse(typeof(BlahType), "blahB");
        int myEnumValue = (int)myEnum;
```